# mean of POSIXct objects with ddply

Tags: r, mean, posixct

I have a dataset with durations (in seconds,vec1) and a group variable (vec2) :

```
df=data.frame(vec1=c(180,7560,16020,300,8940,15120,9600,300,2580,25860,13200,6900,22380,11460,15480),
            vec2=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"))
```

I want to calculate the mean duration for each group. I tested two  ways :

```
test1=plyr::ddply(df, .(vec2), function(x) mean(x$vec1))
test1$V1=as.POSIXct(test1$V1, origin="1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")

test2=plyr::ddply(df, .(vec2), function(x) as.POSIXct(mean(x$vec1), origin="1970-01-01", tz = "GMT"))
```

The results are different (one more hour for test2, the correct answer is given by test1) :

> test1
>     vec2                  V1
>   1    a 1970-01-01 02:13:40
>   2    b 1970-01-01 03:19:33
>
> test2
>     vec2                  V1
>   1    a 1970-01-01 03:13:40
>   2    b 1970-01-01 04:19:33

I know which code gives me the correct answer, but I would like to understand why the result is different. Do you have an explanation ?
Thanks !

Comment: `base` is a package name. Please avoid such names.

Comment: @NelsonGon you are right, sorry, I edited my question

Comment: @NelsonGon R is smart enough to deal with such things. People make a great deal of fuss about nothing at all. In fact `df` is also a function in the stats package, but the code will work nonetheless.

Comment: @HongOoi Thank you for the clarification and information.